# Start a conversation in pidgin from launchy/anywhere

Tags: windows, plugins, pidgin, launchy

I use [pidgin](http://www.pidgin.im/) for all my chatting, and all my regular contacts are available in pidgin roster.

I also use [Launchy](http://www.launchy.net/) to launch a bunch of things.

As a logical consequence, I wonder if it is possible to start a conversation with one of my contacts from launchy, say, by hitting "pidgy [TAB] Contact name", like I already do for, as an example, [PuttY](http://code.google.com/p/putty-launchy-plugin/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using windows 7, the simplest solution to start a conversation without showing Pidgin main window is, too my mind, right-clicking the pidgin icon, then selecting "New message ..." and entering contact name in window.

This is not as good as Launchy, but it does the job quite decently.

Answer (score 3):

- open launchy (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>)
- open **Options** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>)
- go to **Plugins** tab
- select "Runner" from available plugins
- click the plus button to add a new runner and fill in the fields "name", "program" and "arguments"

  - "name" -> whatever you want to type in launchy to start the conversation (eg. *jacob*)
  - "program" -> the path to your pidgin.exe (eg. `C:\Documents and Settings\username\Pidgin\pidgin.exe`)
  - "arguments" -> pidgin arguments (`--protocolhandler=xmpp:*jacob123*@gmail.com?message`)

That's it. Now when you run launchy and type in *jacob* (or whatever) it will open a conversation.  The protocol handler above is for Google Talk. I've only ever tried it for talk. Gor anything else you'll have to figure out what the argument should be.